# How to merge JsonObjects using JAVA which uses javax.json;

Tags: java, json

I have these two JsonObject which uses javax.json. How can i merge these three and have as one Jason Object or JsonArray. Please not that I tried JASONObject and it didnt work as it is org. lib.

```
JsonObject jo = Json.createObjectBuilder()
 .add("click", Json.createArrayBuilder()
    .add(Json.createObjectBuilder()
       .add("object", "Doe")))
 .build();

JsonObject jo1 = Json.createObjectBuilder()
 .add("open", Json.createArrayBuilder()
    .add(Json.createObjectBuilder()
      .add("page", "Doe")
      .add("ms", "5000")))
 .build();

JsonObject jo2 = Json.createObjectBuilder()
 .add("open", Json.createArrayBuilder()
    .add(Json.createObjectBuilder()
      .add("page", "Doe")
      .add("ms", "5000")))
 .build();
```

Comment: add to gather and have as one object

Comment: Yes, but how?  As a single large JSON object, or a JSON array containing JSON objects, or as a JSON object containing JSON objects??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
JSONObject mergeJson = new JSONObject();
mergeJson.putAll(jo1);
mergeJson.putAll(jo2);
mergeJson.putAll(jo3);
```

Comment: This is org.json format. I already tried this and it didn't work. But thanks lot for stopping by

Comment: This answer should be edited to follow the javax.JsonObject instead of org.json as the function calls for org.json is the same as javax.JsonObject and OP didn't ask for org.json.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing org.json library, I ended up writing a utility method of my own as below

Reference : [Merge 2 javax.json.JsonObject](https://crypticarticles.wordpress.com/2015/10/28/merge-2-javax-json-jsonobject/)

```
private JsonObject mergeProfileSummary(JsonObject oldJsonObject, JsonObject newJsonObject) {
        JsonObjectBuilder jsonObjectBuilder =Json.createObjectBuilder();

        for (String key : oldJsonObject.keySet()){
            jsonObjectBuilder.add(key, oldJsonObject.get(key));
        }
        for (String key : newJsonObject.keySet()){
            jsonObjectBuilder.add(key, newJsonObject.get(key));
        }

        return jsonObjectBuilder.build();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed the creating JASONObject part by using org.json lib and it worked;

```
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
jo.put("page", "some val");
jo.put("ms", time);
JSONObject finalObj = new JSONObject();
finalObj.put("open", jo);

JSONObject jo1 = new JSONObject();
jo.put("object", ele.getAttributes().getNamedItem("seleniumwebdriver").getNodeValue());
JSONObject finalObj = new JSONObject();                                 
finalObj.put("click", jo);
```

And here is the code for merging:

```
JSONObject finalArr = new JSONObject();
finalJsonArr.add(jo);
finalJsonArr.add(jo1);
```