# What is the correct way to merge 2 javax.json.JsonObject?

Tags: java, json

I have 2 instances of `javax.json.JsonObect`. I need to merge (not append i.e keys could be same)

`JsonObject` returned by `jsonObjectBuilder` is Immutable, so using putAll isn't option.

Is there any way to use `javax.json.JsonObect.putAll()` as `javax.json.JsonObect` implements Map interface

Kindly suggest/recommend.

Comment: Not absolutely sure this will help, but check out the last answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26036618/how-to-merge-jsonobjects-using-java-which-uses-javax-json

Comment: I tried the same before posting the question. Though one of the answer is marked as correct, if you look into the comments, you will notice that solution doesn't work. I also tried personally and verified that it doesn't work.

Comment: just to make sure - did you look at the bottom?

Comment: @AmosBordowitz Yes, I did but it enforces me to use org.json which i can't

Answer (score 2):

I ended up writing a utility method of my own as below

Reference : [Merge 2 javax.json.JsonObject](https://crypticarticles.wordpress.com/2015/10/28/merge-2-javax-json-jsonobject/)

```
private JsonObject mergeProfileSummary(JsonObject oldJsonObject, JsonObject newJsonObject) {
        JsonObjectBuilder jsonObjectBuilder =Json.createObjectBuilder();

        for (String key : oldJsonObject.keySet()){
            jsonObjectBuilder.add(key, oldJsonObject.get(key));
        }
        for (String key : newJsonObject.keySet()){
            jsonObjectBuilder.add(key, newJsonObject.get(key));
        }

        return jsonObjectBuilder.build();
    }
```